# How to get values for ipi_ifindex for sendmsg()?

Tags: linux, udp, sendmsg

Using `sendmsg()` it is possible to specify from which interface a datagram  will be sent, if a value is set for `in_pktinfo.ipi_ifindex`.

If the packet is a response to a datagram received with `recvmsg()` I can get the interface value from there.

If I just know that the interface if 'eth0' or 'eno1', how can I look up the corresponding `in_pktinfo.ipi_ifindex' value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if_nametoindex()` to convert the interface name to an index.

`if_indextoname()` does the reverse.